# How to Filter Attribute Set, Attribute option value and filter by manufacture in product export

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, collection, filter, export

> Change into **app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on 
>   line 647** in funtion **export()**

```
$collection = $this->_prepareEntityCollection(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'));
```

> Replace code in above code

```
$collection = $this->_customprepareEntityCollection(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 0))
                    //Filter by product name//
                ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('nlike' => '%T-shirts%'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('nlike' => '%Mobile%'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('nlike' => '%Watch%'))

                 //Filter by product option value like manufacture attribute have some option//

                ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 
                array(
                    'nlike' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getAttribute('manufacturer')
                    ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionId('Sony')
                ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 
                array(
                    'nlike' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getAttribute('manufacturer')
                    ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionId('Microsoft')
                ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 
                array(
                    'nlike' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getAttribute('manufacturer')
                    ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionId('LG')
                ))

                  //Filter by particular attribute set like default attribute set id is 4 //

                ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 
                array('eq' => 4));
```